# Angular 2 provider is not working with useValue and function call to new

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, angular-module

I am wondering why Angular 2 providers syntax isn't working when I want to provide a specific value via the `useValue` field.

For instance, in the app.module.ts I have

```
// Abstracted base class (since interfaces don't work with libraries and tsc)
export class Base {
  constructor(public bar:Bar) {
  }
}

export class Foo extends Base {
  constructor(public bar:Bar) {
    super(bar);
  }
}

export class Bar {
  hello = "world";
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
  ],
  providers: [
    {provide: Base, useValue: new Foo(new Bar())}
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

Attempting this throws an error during `ng build`:

```
ERROR in Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Calling function 'Foo', function calls are not supported. Consider replacing the function or lambda with a reference to an exported function, resolving symbol AppModule in /Users/tbeauvais/Code/example-sdk/src/app/app.module.ts, resolving symbol AppModule in /Users/tbeauvais/Code/example-sdk/src/app/app.module.ts
```

I am getting around this by simply using the field, `useClass`, and then specifying the parameters through `deps` like this:

```
...
providers: [
  Bar,
  {provide: Base, useClass: Foo, deps:[Bar]}
],
...
```

It works, it's just not ideal and I am wondering what I am missing here. Also, I don't want to have to inject `Bar` for no reason.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Cheers!

Comment: You should check: https://github.com/rangle/angular-2-aot-sandbox

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know the error sounds cryptic but at the end of the day it is not.
Some configurations (usually the aot-cli ones) do not allow code that cannot be statically analyzed. In order to do that one has to export a function, just like the error states, like this

create a ts file that looks like this

`export function UseClassFunction(){ return function() { return new Foo(new Bar());}}`

and then import that and use it on useValue

`{provide: Base, useValue: UseClassFunction}`